# SVN replication using svn-git

Tags: git, svn, repository, replication

I am facing a problem of syncing two svn servers (one inside and one outside of the firewall). After googling around I found out that svn-git is probably the best alternative.

So the plan is to have an A (inside firewall) and B (outside in the DMZ) svn servers. Then to checkout some folders from A to a git repo then push the changes to B. Afterwards I pick the changes from B into a git and push the changes to A.

Everything has to be done from server A since A is not visible from B. It would be nice to have hooks, but I can just do it once a minute using cron, the load on servers is not high.

Have you got some advice? Can it work?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think git is an alternative at all, not to mention best, given that it can't represent many subversion concepts. I'd suggest [SVK](http://svk.bestpractical.com/view/HomePage), which is decentralized version control tool built on top of subversion. Or if you just need mirror, svnsync might be enough (but I suspect it's not, since it's subversion't own tool and you probably know it when you considered git).

Comment: svnsync seems to make just one way replication, but not two way. Can we use SVK just between server? So that developers may use their beloved svn tools?

Comment: @user383834: Yes, you can access the repositories with arbitrary mix of subversion and svk. Svk is specifically designed to be freely interoperable with svn.